# reload jquery $(function( )... after closing modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I would like to reload all the code inside jquery $(function( ) ... after closing a bootstrap modal window. My Idea is something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  //Code..



$('#mymodal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {

        window.location.reload(); //this is ok to reload the whole page but not what I want
        //I would like to do something like reload $(function())


})
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: try `$(function () {
    domReady();
    $('#mymodal').on('hide.bs.modal', domReady);

    function domReady() {
        //do stuff here
    }
})`

Comment: not working because I cannot close anymore the modal window

Answer (score 0):

If you put your domReady code in a function like this:

```
function myDomReady() {
    // your code here
}

$(document).ready(myDomReady);
```

Then, at any time in the future, you can just call:

```
myDomReady();
```

to execute that code again.